# Se me borran los datos dentro del array - C

Tags: array, c, bucle-for

La funcion lo que tendria que hacer es recibir un valor "a" que es basicamente el numero de una tarjeta de credito y validarla usando el algoritmo de Luhn. El problema esta en este for:

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < MAX;i++)
>     {
>         numerosSeparados[i] = 0;
>         if (numerosMulti[i] >= 10)
>         {
>             numerosSeparados[i] = numerosMulti[i] % 10;
>             numerosMulti[i] = numerosMulti[i] / 10;
>             if (numerosMulti[i] == 1)
>             {
>                 numerosSeparados2[i] = numerosMulti[i];
>                 numerosMulti[i] = 0;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

Ya que usando el dubugger, encontre que de alguna forma cuando sale de ese for, se eliminan los datos contenidos en el array "numerosMulti", cuando tendrian que borrarse nada mas los datos que sean de 2 digitos.

```
int validateCard(long a)
{
    int veces = 0;
    long b = a;
    do
    {
        b = b / 10;
        veces++;
    }while (b>0);

    int tamaño;
    int suma;
    int MAX = veces;
    int numeros[MAX];
    int numerosFuera[MAX / 2];
    int numerosMulti[MAX/2];
    int numerosSeparados[MAX/2];
    int numerosSeparados2[MAX / 2];

    for (int i = 0; a > 0 ; i++)
    {
        numeros[i] = a % 10;
        a = a / 10;
    }
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; j < veces ; i++, j += 2)
    {
        numerosFuera[i] = numeros[j];
    }
    j = 1;
    for (int i = 0; j < veces; i++, j += 2)
    {
        numerosMulti[i] = numeros[j];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        numerosMulti[i] = numerosMulti[i] * 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX;i++)
    {
        numerosSeparados[i] = 0;
        if (numerosMulti[i] >= 10)
        {
            numerosSeparados[i] = numerosMulti[i] % 10;
            numerosMulti[i] = numerosMulti[i] / 10;
            if (numerosMulti[i] == 1)
            {
                numerosSeparados2[i] = numerosMulti[i];
                numerosMulti[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        suma = numerosSeparados[i] + numerosMulti[i] + numerosFuera[i] + numerosSeparados2[i] + suma;
    }
    if (suma % 10 == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que el array no tiene el tamaño adecuado:

En el bucle estás accediendo a las posiciones `[0, MAX-1]`, mientras que el array solo tiene `MAX/2` posiciones. El resto de posiciones no pertenecen al array sino a otras variables del stack y, claro, cuando el valor de esas variables cambia por la razón que sea el efecto que ves es que los valores del array cambian misteriosamente...

La solución es realmente simple, ampliar el tamaño del array:

```
int numerosMulti[MAX];
```